# Constructing elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p[\Gamma_n]$ from $\mathbb{Z}_p[\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{n+1}})/\mathbb{Q})]$

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, group-actions, p-adic-number-theory

Fix a prime $p$ and let $G_n=\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{n+1}})/\mathbb{Q})$. We can identify $G_n$ with $(\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z})^\times$ by mapping $a$ mod $p^{n+1}$ to $\sigma_a:\zeta_{p^{n+1}} \mapsto\zeta_{p^{n+1}}^a$. There is a (unique, if $p$ is odd) decomposition $G_n=\Delta\times \Gamma_n$, where $\Delta\cong (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ and $\Gamma_n\cong\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$. One can now define an 'obvious' map $\mathbb{Z}_p[G_{n}]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p[\Gamma_n]$ as follows. Let $\omega :(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ be the mod $p$ cyclotomic character and $\langle a \rangle$ the projection of $a \in (\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z})^\times$ onto $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, so that $\sigma_{\langle a \rangle}\in \Gamma_n$. We then have a map
$$
\omega^i:\mathbb{Z}_p[G_n]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p[\Gamma_n]
$$
given by $\sum_{a \in (\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z})^\times}c_a\sigma_a\mapsto \sum_{a \in (\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z})^\times}\omega^i(a)c_a\sigma_{\langle a \rangle}$, where $c_a\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and we are extending $\omega$ to $(\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ by precomposing with reduction mod $p$.

There is also another way to define an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p[\Gamma_n]$ from $\mathbb{Z}_p[G_n]$. We can view $\mathbb{Z}_p[G_n]$ as a $\mathbb{Z}_p[\Delta]$-module and take the decomposition coming from orthogonal idempotents. More specifically, if
$$
\epsilon_i=\frac{1}{p-1}\sum_{\sigma\in \Delta}\omega^i(\tau)\tau^{-1}
$$
and if $\vartheta\in \mathbb{Z}_p[G_n]$ we get that $\epsilon_i\vartheta$ lies in the $\omega^i$-eigenspace of $\mathbb{Z}_p[G_n]$, i.e, a copy of $\mathbb{Z}_p[\Gamma_n]$ where $\tau\in \Delta$ acts by multiplication by $\omega^i(\tau)$.

My intuition tells me that these two methods of defining an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p[\Gamma_n]$ by 'projection' from  $\mathbb{Z}_p[G_n]$ should be the same, i.e., that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\epsilon_i\vartheta=\omega^i(\vartheta),
\end{equation}
but for some reason I'm having a hard time showing this. Is this equation (1) true?

I think this is either easy and I'm getting myself confused or possibly it's just not true... In any case, here are some thoughts: In general, one has $\tau\epsilon_{\chi}=\chi(\tau)\epsilon_{\chi}$ for a character $\chi\in \hat \Delta$. Thus, since we can decompose $\sigma_a=\tau_a\sigma_{\langle a\rangle}$ for some $\tau_a\in \Delta$, we have
$$
\epsilon_i \vartheta= \epsilon_i \sum_{a\in (\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z})^\times}\omega^i(\tau_a)c_a \sigma_{\langle a \rangle}=\frac{1}{p-1}\sum_{\tau\in \Delta}\sum_{a\in (\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z})^\times}\omega^i(\tau\tau_a)c_a \sigma_{\langle a \rangle}\tau^{-1}.
$$
After staring at this for far too long and fiddling with reindexing, I am still not sure why this should be equal to $\omega^i(\vartheta)=\sum_{a \in (\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z})^\times}\omega^i(a)c_a\sigma_{\langle a \rangle}$...

Comment: $\sigma_{\langle a \rangle} \in \Gamma_n$ ??

Comment: Yes - doesn't that work? Essentially, if $\sigma_a\in G_n= \Delta\times \Gamma_n$ then $\sigma_{\langle a\rangle}$ is meant to be the projection onto the $\Gamma_n$ factor.

Comment: Maybe I should have defined $\langle a\rangle$ to be $\gamma^j$, where $\gamma\in (\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z})^\times$ generates the cyclic subgroup of order $p^n$ and $0\leq j \leq p^n-1$ is some integer depending on $a$.

Comment: anything unclear

Comment: I'm still filling in some details and making sure I understand your notation (it is clearer than mine, which I appreciate...). I think what you're saying is (A) my 'question' isn't really well-defined (i.e., equation (1) doesn't actually make sense) and (B) what is really going on is that the 'multiplication by idempotent map' (on the left of equation 1)  factors through the ring homomorphism on the right of equation 1. So, is it correct to say that the maps I defined above are not equal, but just that one factors through the other?

Comment: Yes. It shows that every $e_j \Bbb{Z}[G_n]$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}[G_n^{p-1}]$ and since $e_ie_j=0$ we have $\Bbb{Z}[G_n]\cong \Bbb{Z}[G_n^{p-1}]^{p-1}$. The maps are homomorphisms so it suffices to check with $g$ and $1+p$ (this notation is terrible, $1+p$ in $G_n$ not $\Bbb{Z}_p$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $p$ odd prime with $g$ of order $p-1$ and $1+p$ of order $p^{n-1}$ the generators of $G_n=\Bbb{Z/p^nZ}^\times$. Let $r(p-1)=1\bmod p^{n-1}$ so that $\sigma\to \sigma^{r(p-1)}$ is the natural projection $G_n\to G_n^{p-1}=\Gamma_n$.

Let
$$e_j = \frac1{p-1}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} g^k \zeta_{p-1}^{kj}\in \Bbb{Z}_p[G_n], \qquad e_j^2 = e_j, \qquad \omega(g^m (1+p)^r) = \zeta_{p-1}^m\in \Bbb{Z}_p$$

Then for $\sigma\in G_n$ $$e_j \sigma  =e_j\sigma^{r(p-1)}\omega(\sigma)^{-j} \in \Bbb{Z}_p[G_n]$$

The map (non-unital ring endomorphism of $\Bbb{Z}_p[G_n]$) $$\sigma \to e_j \sigma^{r(p-1)}\omega(\sigma)^{-j} $$
factors through the ring homomorphism $$\sigma\to \sigma^{r(p-1)}\omega(\sigma)^{-j} ,\qquad \Bbb{Z}_p[G_n]\to \Bbb{Z}_p[G_n^{p-1}]$$